# Can I use ifeq / else if eq / else syntax with any conditional? Or must I test just one variable against multiple values. (like a case.)

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

The make documentation says the syntax of a complex conditional is as follows:

```
conditional-directive-one
text-if-one-is-true
else conditional-directive-two
text-if-two-is-true
else
text-if-one-and-two-are-false
endif
```

But all the examples I have seen each "conditional-directive-n" is testing the same $var as in the first conditional-directive-one.  In effect it is like a case statement testing one variable against multiple possible values.  Like this:

```
ifeq ($(option), 1)
    CC=gcc
else ifeq ($(option), 2)
    CC=clang
else
    CC=mipsel-linux-gcc
endif
```

My question is, is this a requirement?  Or could I have complete different conditional-directives like this:

```
ifeq ($(option), 1)
    CC=gcc
else ifeq ($(myhostname), "JohnsLaptop")
    CC=johnsCompiler
else
    CC=
endif
```

So is it really just a funky syntax for a case statement, or is each 'else ifeq' independent.

I know I can do this:

```
ifeq ($(option), 1)
    CC=gcc
else
ifeq ($(myhostname), "johnsLaptop")
    CC=johnsCompiler
else
    CC=mipsel-linux-gcc
endif
endif
```

But thats ugly.  I would rather not have nested if/else without indentation if I don't have to.

Comment: I mean, you can just try it and see, faster than you can ask us.  But the answer is, every conditional is independent.  There's no need for any of the conditionals to be related in any way.

Comment: Yes, I could and did test it, but my version of make is non-standard and I wanted to know what the "standard" make rule was.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 6):

I tested this on my non-standard version of make and the answer was that each conditional directive is independant.  And thanks to a comment from [madScientist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939557/madscientist), it seems confirmed that this is the correct answer for standard and gnumake as well.\

This code works:

```
ifneq ($(findstring mbist_rtl,$@),)
    RTL_OPT = mixed findSrc_targets_memwrap.ini
else ifeq ($(DFT), 1)
    RTL_OPT = dft
else ifeq ($(BB), 1)
    RTL_OPT = ndft
else
    RTL_OPT = syn
endif
```